# Filtrar o retorno de Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Criei a seguinte SP:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_processoFinalizado`(IN mantenedor int(11))
BEGIN

select 
        `p`.`protocolo` AS `protocolo`,
        `p`.`id` AS `idProcesso`,
        `p`.`der` AS `der`,
        `p`.`data_habilitacao` AS `dhab`,
        `p`.`id_usuario` AS `idUsuario`,
p.mantenedor as mantenedor,
        `ap`.`id_andamento` AS `codAndamento`,
        `ap`.`data` AS `dataAndamento`,
        `ap`.`observacao` AS `observacao`,
        `ap`.`id_usuario` AS `idUsuarioEvento`,
        `u`.`nome` AS `nome`,
        `u`.`matricula` AS `matricula`,
        `u`.`lotacao` AS `lotacao`,
        (to_days(`ap`.`data`) - to_days(`p`.`der`)) AS `tempoConclusao`,
        (to_days(`ap`.`data`) - to_days(`p`.`data_habilitacao`)) AS `tempoDecisao`,
        `a`.`descricao` AS `desAndamento`
    from
        (((`processo` `p`
        join `andamento_processo` `ap` ON ((`p`.`id` = `ap`.`id_processo`)))
        join `usuario` `u` ON ((`u`.`id` = `p`.`id_usuario`)))
        join `andamento` `a` ON ((`ap`.`id_andamento` = `a`.`id`)))
    where
        (`p`.`bol_finalizado` = 'S')
  and p.mantenedor  = mantenedor
    order by `p`.`der` , `p`.`data_habilitacao`;


END
```

A chamada dela pelo codigo 
`CALL sp_processoFinalizado(2225566)`
me retornam os dados de maneira correta.

Minha questão é como filtrar esses dados antes de chegar no PHP.

Por exemplo :

```
CALL sp_processoFinalizado(2225566) where tempoDecisao < 30;
```

Nesse caso eu quero informar uma parâmetro para a SP e com esse retorno eu desejo aplicar um filtro, que nessa ocasião será a cláusala where.

Já consegui fazer isso usando views mas quando a massa de dados é muito grande, temos um gargalo, pois sao carregados os processos independente da lotacao que no caso é o parâmetro informado, para depois aplicar o filtro. 
 Assim gostaria de melhorar a performance listando apenas os que interessam para depois aplicar o filtro por isso pensei em usar  SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer fazer é impossível via Stored Procedures devido a forma que ela funciona, como se você uma função fechada.

Caso precise incrementar sua consulta você pode:

1 - Inserir esse parâmetro como argumento da sua Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_processoFinalizado`(IN mantenedor int(11), IN tempo int(11))
BEGIN

select 
        `p`.`protocolo` AS `protocolo`,
        `p`.`id` AS `idProcesso`,
        `p`.`der` AS `der`,
        `p`.`data_habilitacao` AS `dhab`,
        `p`.`id_usuario` AS `idUsuario`,
p.mantenedor as mantenedor,
        `ap`.`id_andamento` AS `codAndamento`,
        `ap`.`data` AS `dataAndamento`,
        `ap`.`observacao` AS `observacao`,
        `ap`.`id_usuario` AS `idUsuarioEvento`,
        `u`.`nome` AS `nome`,
        `u`.`matricula` AS `matricula`,
        `u`.`lotacao` AS `lotacao`,
        (to_days(`ap`.`data`) - to_days(`p`.`der`)) AS `tempoConclusao`,
        (to_days(`ap`.`data`) - to_days(`p`.`data_habilitacao`)) AS `tempoDecisao`,
        `a`.`descricao` AS `desAndamento`
    from
        (((`processo` `p`
        join `andamento_processo` `ap` ON ((`p`.`id` = `ap`.`id_processo`)))
        join `usuario` `u` ON ((`u`.`id` = `p`.`id_usuario`)))
        join `andamento` `a` ON ((`ap`.`id_andamento` = `a`.`id`)))
    where
        (`p`.`bol_finalizado` = 'S')
  and p.mantenedor  = mantenedor
  and (to_days(`ap`.`data`) - to_days(`p`.`data_habilitacao`)) < tempo 
    order by `p`.`der` , `p`.`data_habilitacao`;


END
```

2 - Cria uma pseudo `Materialized View`. Conceitualmente seria uma View com uma tabela concreta por trás com o objetivo de melhorar a performance. Como o MySQL não dispõe dessa funcionalidade por padrão, você pode implementar na mão esse tipo de mecanismo.

Não vou entrar em detalhes por ser algo complexo e alongaria muito a minha resposta, porém você pode consultar como fazer isso [aqui<sup>en</sup>](http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-materialized-views).